# How pytorch uses an implicit for loop instead of an explicit for loop？

Tags: python, pytorch, numpy-ndarray

The code is as follows:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
x = torch.zeros((128, 3, 32, 32))
y = np.arange(128)
for i in range(len(y)):
    x[i].uniform_(-y[i], y[i])
```

Can the for loop be replaced with something like array slicing?
Thanks

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that there is a problem with the code I gave, I have modified it. x can be understood as a sample with a number of 128 and a size of 3*32*32. I want to assign a different uniformly distributed random value to each sample. For example, the uniform distribution range of the first sample is (-1,1), The second sample is uniformly distributed in the range (-2,2), and so on. So is it possible to do this without using a for loop?thanks again for your answer:)

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of the following fact:

Given a random variable `Z ~ Uniform(0,1)` and real numbers `a` and `b` where `a < b`, if `X = Z * (b - a) + a` then `X ~ Uniform(a,b)`. Particularly relevant is the case where `a = -b` which allows us to simplify to `X = (2 * Z - 1) * b`.

Putting this into practice in PyTorch looks something like this

```py
z = torch.rand(128, 3, 32, 32)
y = torch.arange(128).reshape(-1, 1, 1, 1)
x = (2 * z - 1) * y
```

where [`torch.rand`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.rand.html#torch-rand) returns a new random tensor sampled from `Uniform(0,1)`. We also had to insert some extra unitary dimensions to `y` using [`Tensor.reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.reshape.html#torch-tensor-reshape) to make it shape `[128,1,1,1]` so that broadcasting will work the way we want it to (see [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) if you're unfamiliar with broadcast semantics in NumPy and PyTorch, they both use the same rules). Also note that we use [`torch.arange`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.arange.html#torch-arange) instead of `np.arange` since we generally want to stay in the PyTorch framework when performing mathematical operations on PyTorch tensors (because PyTorch tensors don't usually play nice with NumPy arrays).

Comment: I'm so dependent on the pytorch framework itself that I forgot how to think about problems, thank you!  :)